# Setting hex background on all view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicolor

Hey guys I have the following:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     [super viewDidLoad];
        // SET BACKGROUND OF APPLICATION ON STARTUP
     [self.view setBackgroundColor: [self colorWithHexString:@"88C800"]];

     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(UIColor*)colorWithHexString:(NSString*)hex
{
    NSString *cString = [[hex stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] uppercaseString];

    // String should be 6 or 8 characters
    if ([cString length] < 6) return [UIColor grayColor];

    // strip 0X if it appears
    if ([cString hasPrefix:@"0X"]) cString = [cString substringFromIndex:2];

    if ([cString length] != 6) return  [UIColor grayColor];

    // Separate into r, g, b substrings
    NSRange range;
    range.location = 0;
    range.length = 2;
    NSString *rString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 2;
    NSString *gString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    range.location = 4;
    NSString *bString = [cString substringWithRange:range];

    // Scan values
    unsigned int r, g, b;
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:rString] scanHexInt:&r];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:gString] scanHexInt:&g];
    [[NSScanner scannerWithString:bString] scanHexInt:&b];

    return [UIColor colorWithRed:((float) r / 255.0f)
                           green:((float) g / 255.0f)
                            blue:((float) b / 255.0f)
                           alpha:1.0f];
}
```

This will change the background color of my `view controller (root)` to the specified hex color I supply.  My issue is, when navigating to another `view controller`, how do I get the above function to effect all of my `view controllers`?  This code is within my `ViewController.m`

Not to sure what I need to do, suggestions and thoughts?

Comment: Damn it makes me an eye sore, could u edit the code shifting etc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest two things:

1. Make your `colorWithHexString:` a category class method on `UIColor`. Then you can access the method from any class that imports your category .h file.
2. If you want every view controller in your app to have a customer color (or other common behavior), you should create a common base class such as `MyBaseViewController`. Have this class extend `UIViewController` then have all of your app's view controllers extend `MyBaseViewController`. Put all common setup in the base class. If you also need some table view controllers then create a `MyBaseTableViewController` class with similar code.

Comment: @maddy what do you suggest?

Comment: @DavidBiga Is your comment meant to be a joke?

Comment: @maddy I see sorry what I mean, what is the best way to go about this? haha sorry

Comment: @DavidBiga I was going to say "I suggest those two things". :) Be specific. Best way to do what? I thought I was pretty clear.

Comment: What I mean is, I don't have experiance using both of those options you suggested.  So what I mean is out of those 2 what is the best suggestion in you're opinion to take.

Comment: You do both. It's not either/or.

Comment: Oh I see, do you have any documentation?

Comment: I joined the discussion.

Comment: There are plenty of existing questions here covering how to add a category method. matt's answer shows you too. As for creating a base class that all of your other classes extend, that's just simple Objective-C class creation.

Comment: No discussion - it clicked that by mistake and instantly closed it out.

Comment: Okay :)  Ya thats what I thought, I am just trying to get the gist of Obj-C

Comment: @DavidBiga, maddy's advice is excellent (as usual.) Since you don't know about categories, and don't know about subclassing UIViewController, it seems like it's time to go do some research on those 2 topics. Both are fundamental concepts in Objective C.

Answer (score 1):

You can't readily do this using an instance method. You should do two things: (1) promote `colorWithHexString:` to be a UIColor class method (using a category); (2) if you're going to be using this same color in a lot of places, put the color where you can get at it from anywhere, such as your *.pch* file or some other header that everyone can import.

Here's an example from my own code:

```
// MyIncudes.h
@interface UIColor (mycats)
+ (UIColor*) myGolden;
+ (UIColor*) myPaler;
@end

// MyIncludes.m
@implementation UIColor (mycats)
+ (UIColor*) myGolden {
    return [self colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.894 blue:0.541 alpha:.900];
}
+ (UIColor*) myPaler {
    return [self colorWithRed:1.000 green:0.996 blue:0.901 alpha:1.000];
}
@end
```

Now anyone who imports *MyIncludes.h* has access to these colors.

Comment: so couldn't I simply do this in the ViewController.h than?

Comment: You can't guarantee that there will always be a ViewController instance to talk to, so it needs to be a class method. But in that case, you should put in a neutral, appropriate location; that's why I suggest a UIColor category. You don't want all other classes to have knowledge of ViewController that they don't need to have.

Comment: Because when you create a category of UIColor, it adds methods to UIColor.  In your case, you want a class method +(UIColor) colorWithHexString: (NSString *) hexString; That way, any time you want to create a color using a hex string, you just use the method, even if it's in a subclass of UIButton, or anywhere in your program.